# numpy.genfromtxt: Ambiguous delimiters?

Tags: python, numpy, delimiter, genfromtxt

I'm trying to write a generic script, part of which imports files that are either comma-separated or white-space-separated.  I'd like the script to recognize either type.  Is there a way to specify something like

```
arrayobj = np.genfromtxt(file.txt, delimiter=(',' OR '\t'), names=None, dtype=None)
```

I tried using a regular expression (`',|\t'`) but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I dont believe you can use np.genfromtxt for this. The delimiter argument is passed directly to the python standard library `str.split(delimiter)`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned I do not believe there is a way to do this with `np.genfromtxt`; however you can always use python pandas.

```
example.txt:
1,2,3 #Header
1,2,3
4,5'tab'6
7'tab'8'tab'9
```

Using pandas `read_csv`:

```
print pd.read_csv('example.csv',sep='\t|,').values
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```